# Ember SyntaxError Unexpected Token; NodeJS Module Related

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I am having an issue with Ember building. I have tried doing `npm clean cache`, deleting the `node_modules` folder, and then `npm install`. I have also tried copying the `ember-cli` and `ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile` folders from sources that I know build correctly and are using the same versions.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Project.require (*****\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:280:12)
    at Project.config (*****\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:198:26)
    at Class.module.exports.projectConfig (*****\node_modules\ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile\index.js:103:25)
```

Comment: which version of node

Comment: >node -v
> v4.4.4

Comment: any reason you can't use the latest LTS version (4.6.0) - just a thought, as the error + trace you've posted doesn't really show much

Comment: Build server; limited privileges. Trying to get 4.6.0 installed now.

Comment: 4.6.0 produces the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and searching, I ran across [this question](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/server-wont-start-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-at-exports-runinthiscontext-vm-js-53-16/9012). It turns out that my /config/environment.js was corrupt, which was resulting in this error.